# Git believes tracked files are untracked when switching branches

Tags: git

From master branch, create a new branch and push to remote

```
git checkout -b not_master (example second branch)
git checkout not_master
git push origin not_master
```

Now my local working copy is on the `not_master` branch.

I've renamed all files where the first character of the file name is in lowercase to uppercase.

I noticed git did not record the case changes so I updated my config using

```
git config core.ignorecase false
```

I then committed and pushed the changes to `not_master`

Here's where the issue arises, when attempting to switch back to `master` git informs me that there are untracked files present and those untracked files will be overwritten by checkout, the untracked files are all of the files where I changed the filename.

How can I keep two branches with the same files that only differ in filename?

If I checkout master using the `f` flag then all files that have been renamed will be deleted in master.

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Did you do `git add` and `git commit` prior to your `git push` ?

Comment: @AlexW No, I typically never have to add when branching from a currently existing branch - I did commit and push the filename changes however.

Comment: Chk the changes with "git status" you will see what files are added, what changed etc.

Comment: also "git checkout -b not_master" is checking out your branch, so no point of checking it out again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `git mv <oldfilename> <newfilename>` for each file

The config option `core.ignorecase` is `false` by default and only adds optimizations for filesystems that don't support case-sensitivity.  Git thinks you deleted these files and added new ones when it detects case changes.  To prevent that unwanted behavior, you have to tell git that you're renaming them.

> If true, this option enables various workarounds to enable Git to work
>   better on filesystems that are not case sensitive, like FAT. For
>   example, if a directory listing finds "makefile" when Git expects
>   "Makefile", Git will assume it is really the same file, and continue
>   to remember it as "Makefile".

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-coreignoreCase

```
alex:~/workspace/test (not_master) $ git mv readme.txt README.txt
alex:~/workspace/test (not_master) $ git status
On branch not_master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        renamed:    readme.txt -> README.txt

alex:~/workspace/test (not_master) $ 
alex:~/workspace/test (not_master) $ git commit -m "Renamed files"
[not_master 2b7c940] Renamed files
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename readme.txt => README.txt (100%)
alex:~/workspace/test (not_master) $ git push
alex:~/workspace/test (not_master) $ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
```

Comment: So the workflow would be `checkout new branch` > rename files (while having git ignore case changes > then performing a `mv` for each changed filename? Would something like `git mv /path/to/dir/*` move all files in the dir?

Comment: Also, as a general rule, users should not be fussing with the `core.ignoreCase` setting. Git sets this based on careful probing of the file system at `git init` time (including the `git init` run by `git clone`); afterward, Git assumes that `core.ignoreCase` correctly describes the behavior of the OS. So if you change it but the OS still behaves as it did yesterday, you're just setting yourself up to have more trouble with case folding... (In other words, if setting it lets you do a trick, well, do the trick, then set it back!)